# Как добавить кастомный CSS внутрь WebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

Суть такая: есть `WebView`, в который передается строка, содержащая HTML.
Выглядит так:

```
let newsHTML = receviedNewsText
viewNewsHTML.loadHTMLString(newsHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

`viewNewsHTML` - собственно, сам `WebView`;
`receviedNewsText` - это HTML (из тегов там только p и иногда a), который достается с сервера через JSON.
Поскольку там нет никаких стилей, то текст обычный, маленький, некрасивый.

Задача в том, чтобы внутри WebView я мог использовать стили для тега p.

Как это можно сделать? Идеально, если это будет файл .css внутри приложения, стили из которого будут подгружаться в WebView. Но может есть какой-то другой способ.

Буду признателен за советы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123093/insert-css-into-loaded-html-in-uiwebview)

Вот такой пример кода, чтоб увеличить размер шрифта используя css

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *cssString = @"body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 50px }"; // 1
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)"; // 2
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString]; // 3
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptWithCSSString]; // 4
}
```

Swift

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let cssString = "body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 50px }"
    let javascriptString = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style)"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascriptString)
}
```

Comment: Было бы хорошо, чтобы это было на Swift. :) Но моих навыков хватило для того, чтобы переписать на нем. :)

Comment: добавил в ответ